# How to change angular's default module

Tags: angular, module, components, default

While learning about angular modules, I started wondering if we can change the angular's default module or not.
I tried it but failed.
Changes I made to the files:

I created a new dir under src directory named: core which contains the following class: core.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CoreComponent }  from './core.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ CoreComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ CoreComponent ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

core dir also contains the core.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'core',
    template: `<h2> Core Component Welcome you</h2>`
})
export class CoreComponent { }
```

Following changes were made to the main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(CoreModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

and index.html

```
<core>loading core component</core>
```

I know in real world scenario no one would bother changing the app module, but i just want to understand how things work, so if you can kindly help me understand how things are working, what am i missing, or if its not even possible to change the default module.

Update:
Console doesn't report any errors, but the content doesn't load. Instead of displaying (comes from core.component.ts template portion):

> Core Component Welcome you.

It's only displaying (comes from index.html portion):

> loading core component

Comment: Can i see your error?

Comment: Console doesn't report any errors, but the content doesn't load. Instead of displaying:
Core Component Welcome you.
it's only displaying:
loading core component

Comment: check this demo I created base of your code it work fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-def-module 

Comment: I don't know what went wrong there but i tried it now and it's working fine now. https://stackblitz.com/edit/change-app-root

Comment: Thanks to @Fmerco for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

app.module is consider a root module and root module has just few difference from other angular module

1️⃣ import `BrowserModule`

2️⃣ one of the declared component at latest must add to bootstrap array

3️⃣ add a element in the `index.html` match the bootstrap components selector

4️⃣ set the new module as root module by pass a module refrence to `bootstrapModule` method of  `platformBrowserDynamic` object at main.ts.

*core.module.ts*

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule], //  1️⃣
  declarations: [CoreComponent],
  bootstrap: [CoreComponent] //  2️⃣
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

*index.html*

```html
<core>loading</core> <!-- //  3️⃣-->
```

*main.ts*

```js
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(CoreModule) //  4️⃣
 .then(ref => {

 })
 .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-def-module)

> check this [bootstrapping](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping)  for more details.